# Simple method that returns an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The question is
"In Q1A write a method called getIntArraySize8() that returns an array that can store 8 integers."
It also says you should only use one statement

This is my code

```
public class Q1A {
    int [] getIntArraySize8(){
        int [] questionOne = new int[8];
        return questionOne;
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that there is only one statement in the method?

Comment: I updated your tags assuming this is Java. Correct it if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than declaring and initializing a local variable in one statement then returning it in another, just return a new array that can store 8 integers in a single statement as follows:

```
public class Q1A {
    int [] getIntArraySize8(){
        return new int[8]; // a single statement to get the job done
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] getIntArraySize8() {
    return new int[8];
}
```

The `new int[8]` part is the part that returns an array and you're storing it a variable for no reason.

Also please mark the language and do research before posting, its obvious when its a homework question.